# How to plot two regression lines from a GLM using two predictor variables which are on the same scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot regression lines from models I have run exploring the effect of native and non-native biomass on reproductive metrics of birds (whilst accounting for relevant confounding variables). Using the below linear model as an example with day of first egg as the response variable:

```
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)         45.38841    9.55586   4.750  0.00208 **
Native_biomass      -0.50256    0.18359  -2.737  0.02903 * 
Non_native_biomass  -0.16094    0.09672  -1.664  0.14007   
SpeciesGreat_tit     0.29105    4.21291   0.069  0.94685   
No_tree_species     -0.77424    0.58555  -1.322  0.22765   
Distance_to_light   -0.28324    0.14644  -1.934  0.09435 . 
Anthropogenic_cover -0.02871    0.06234  -0.461  0.65909   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Currently, I am using the effect_plot function to create two separate plots:

```
effect_plot(lm5, pred= Native_biomass, 
                                interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE,
                                x.label="Native Biomass %", y.label="Lay day of first egg",
                                main.title = "Effect of increasing native biomass on the day 
                        of first egg being layed",
                                colors="seagreen", point.alpha=0.6, rug=TRUE)

effect_plot(lm5, pred= Non_native_biomass, 
                                interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE,
                                x.label="Non_native_biomass %", y.label="Lay day of first egg",
                                main.title = "Effect of increasing non-native biomass on 
the day of first egg being layed",
                                colors="seagreen", point.alpha=0.6, rug=TRUE)
```

This has produced the below two plots:

[image: Two separate plots]

What I want to do is plot them both on the same chart. I.e. the X axis label becomes 'Biomass' and then I have two regression lines of two different colours. One for Native biomass and one for Non-native biomass.

Is there a way in which I can do this? I want to be able to do this for two LMs and for two GLMs so that I have a total of 4 plots.